# Linux find command shell expansion

Tags: linux, sh, glob

I have just a little question I don't understand with the **find** command.

I can do this :

```
[root@hostnaoem# ❯❯❯ls /proc/*/fd
```

But this give me an error :

```
[root@hostnaoem# ❯❯❯ find /proc/*/fd -ls
find: `/proc/*/fd': No such file or directory
```

even if I use **"/proc/*/fd"***, **/proc/""/fd** or **"/proc/*/fd"**

I've searched wha **find** shell expansion says about that, but I found nothing. Can someone tell me why?

Thanks

Comment: Try `find /proc/ -type d -exec find {} -name fd -type f \ `. This finds every directory in `/proc/`, then finds every file in said directory with the name `fd`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. `find /proc/*/fd -ls` works fine with GNU `find`, and BSD `find` that ships with Mac OS X accepts multiple path arguments as well. The error message you show is what I would expect from `find "/proc/*/fd" -ls` (with the pattern quoted).

Answer (score 0):

If you just RTFM, you'll learn that the syntax for find is:

```
find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-D debugopts] [-Olevel] [path...] [expression]
```

The usually used subset of that is:

```
find whereToSearch (-howToSearch arg)*
```

To find all files|directories named `fd` in `/proc`:

```
find /proc -name fd
```

`-name` is the most common howToSearch expression:

> -name pattern
>
> ```
>           Base of  file  name  (the  path  with  the  leading  directories
>           removed)  matches  shell  pattern  pattern.   The metacharacters
>           (`*', `?', and `[]') match a `.' at the start of the  base  name
>           (this is a change in findutils-4.2.2; see section STANDARDS CON‐
>           FORMANCE below).  To ignore a directory and the files under  it,
>           use  -prune; see an example in the description of -path.  Braces
>           are not recognised as being special, despite the fact that  some
>           shells  including  Bash  imbue  braces with a special meaning in
>           shell patterns.  The filename matching is performed with the use
>           of  the  fnmatch(3)  library function.   Don't forget to enclose
>           the pattern in quotes in order to protect it from  expansion  by
>           the shell.
> ```

(Note the the last sentence)

If your pattern contains slashes, you need `-path` or `-wholename` (same thing):

```
find /proc/ -wholename '/proc/[0-9]*/fd' 2>/dev/null
```

Other expressions you might want to use are:
     -type
     -depth, -mindepth, -maxdepth
     -user, -uid

See [find(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) to learn more about each search expressions. If you want to search the in-terminal manual (`man find` or `man 1 find`), you can use the `/` character to enter search mode (like `Ctrl+F` in most GUI apps).

---

Usage of `ls` with globbing (`*`) is generally a code smell. Unless you use the `-d` flag, it'll list the contents of the directories that match the glob pattern in addition to the matches.
I find the `echo globpattern` form generally more convenient for viewing the results of a glob pattern match.

Answer (score 0):

This work :

```
[root@hostname # ❯❯❯ find /proc/ -path /proc/*/fd -ls
```

Regards.

Comment: Surely you meant `'/proc/*/fd'`